# How to query service list in Windows 10 including templates (but not instances!) for per-user services

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-services, wmi

I need a list of names (keys) of Windows services. Windows 10 introduced a concept of per-user services that creates new service instances with LUID (Locally Unique IDs) attached to their names. I need to *ignore* these instances, but resulting list should contain templates for them.

For example if there is running service `ContactData_443f50` I need to have `ContactData` listed in output (without LUID and duplication for multiple users logged in)

I've already used WMI query `select * from Win32_Service` to look up service names, but the list contains instances of per-user services and does not contain templates for them.

I've also run `sc.exe queryex` - this list provided me with per-user services clearly marked as such. I would need to parse the output through, and I am not sure about potential localization or future-proof of that solution

I would prefer using WMI for the task.

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine or remote via WMI?

Comment: @EylM On local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

win32_service does not return "per-user services" information. Personally, I would look for it in the registry.
E.g :
HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ WpnUserService_3ce1a
    (REG_DWORD) Type: 224
HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ WpnUserService
    (REG_DWORD) Type: 96

"per-user services" is always 224.

Comment: Sometimes the type of service instances (per-user services) is 208. See the CredentialEnrollmentManagerUserSvc service